# How to make a contemporary browser treat a `srcdoc`-based iframe as if it was served from a different origin?

Tags: security, iframe, content-security-policy, sandbox, same-origin-policy

From my understanding, serving untrusted content in an iframe with a different origin is desirable, as browsers’ native mechanisms for isolating origins from each other have necessarily evolved to be very robust.

Which leads to a question: is it possible to make a modern browser treat an iframe that was constructed programmatically using a `srcdoc` attribute (or a data URI and `src` attribute, mostly equivalent I suppose) as if that iframe belonged to a different origin, so as to enforce isolation further?

Comment: Yes, this is what the iframe `sandbox` attribute is for ;)

Comment: So, you are saying it’s the same as setting the `sandbox` attribute programmatically after creating the iframe, right? Which value should the attribute have to match the default behavior of a different-origin iframe? I assume it would at least have `allow-scripts`, because AFAIK scripts are not allowed in sandboxed iframes by default…

Comment: It's the same yes. `allow-downloads allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-scripts` should be enough to cover most use case.

It will 99% match the default behavior of a different-origin. There might be exception thought, see my own question for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77489967/same-origin-policy-between-iframes-without-origins-iframeception