# Same Origin Policy between iframes without origins -- Iframeception

Tags: iframe, same-origin-policy

Our application used to embed a third party without being too cautious, using the following working code:

```html
<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms" srcdoc="<script src='https://thirdparty.com/script.js'></script>"></iframe>
```

I wish to remove `allow-same-origin` to prevent this third party from having access to anything from our domain as the third party does not need it.

However, it happens that this script creates a new iframe (within the iframe sandbox we have). The iframe src is `about:blank` and the first iframe communicates with its child with   `contentWindow`.

It seems that our site, our site's child iframe and the iframe's child iframe used to share the same domain thanks to `allow-same-origin`. Now that it was removed, the site's iframe and the iframe's child both share a `null` origin it seems, which is not accepted by the same origin policy and result in the following error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read a named property 'document' from 'Window': Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

To resume, this are the origins with `sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms"`:

```
site.com
  |===> iframe A (origin: site.com)
        |===> iframe B (origin: site.com)
```

This are the origins with `sandbox="allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms"`

```
site.com
  |==> iframe A (origin: null)
       |===> iframe B (origin: null)
```

This is the origins that I wish:

```
site.com
  |==> iframe A (origin: some origin that is not site.com ?)
       |===> iframe B (origin: some origin that is not site.com ?)
```

What options do I have so that the iframe and the iframe's child share the same origin, and that our site and the iframes do not ?

Comment: Note that since I control the content of `srcdoc`, I could eventually add an additional script which would create short circuit for the creation of iframe `B` to change some attributes of it before creation, but what to ?